# Android TV: What is the better approach to customise SearchFragment -- Extend LeanBack or Build a CustomView from scratch?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I'm new to AndoridTV. I have to customise Search View, please refer to.

[image]

Should I extend Leanback Search Fragment and customise? or Create a CustomView. Please suggest, what is recommended. Will I face any issues, if I don't use Leanback for SearchView?

Comment: Have you tried implementing either of them? If not, I would suggest trying to implement them first before anything else, so you have an idea of what works best for you. You can post a question again when you encounter a problem with implementation.

Comment: Thanks Jacque for your response. I have done custom implementation and it is working fine.